# Standardized md5 hashing in typescript (Angular)

Tags: python, angular, typescript, hash, md5

I am trying to generate an id that is generated in the backend, in the frontend (not the best of practices, I know). The id is an Md5 hash of several (dynamically generated, i.e, I don't know the hash in advance) strings concatenated together. So what I tried to do is to use the Md5 class (in `ts-md5/dist/md5`) to create an Md5 hash:

```
getId(s1: string, s2: string, s3: string) : string {
    return Md5.hashStr(`${s1}/${s2}/${s3}`);
}
```

But, the hash returned by the backend did not match the hash returned by `getId()`.

Here is how I create the hash in the backend (Python):

```py
id = hashlib.md5("some_string_seed".encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
```

I thought that maybe the problem is in the encoding, but adding encoding didn't change anything:

```
encode_utf8( s )
{
  return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}
return Md5.hashStr(encode_utf8(`${s1}/${s2}/${s3}`));
```

I tried some basic examples but the hashes just don't match.

How do I make the hashes the same? (cannot modify the backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to use `crypto-js`, whose md5 hashing algorithm produces the same result as the `hashlib`, Python library.